# What's the type relationship between "number" and "any" in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Typescript has two kinds of compatibility: subtype and assignment (according to [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#advanced-topics)).

while testing this code[[playground link]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAaQDRQCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoEA+KAXigG8oBrCEALjSgF8BuAWAChfRIUAIYBGSrDhDcIFLgCuAWwBGEAE6luPAdCEAmcfHnK1KKSA29+4aACFEKVOSrosOAsQRQA-FDEtdmlaCSmJUdmayiirqmtpQSvphcEbRptIWfDxAA):

```js
type A<K, T extends K> = { key: T };

type a1 = A<any, number>;
type a2 = A<number, any>;  // a2 = {key:any}

type B<K, T> = T extends K ? 1 : 2;

type b1 = B<any, number>;
type b2 = B<number, any>;
```

Obviously, `a1` is `{key:number}`.

But why `a2` is works and equal to `{key:any}`? If this problem doesn't confused, then `b2` equal to `1 | 2` is make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In typescript *everything* matches `any`, except `never`

Comment: Except `never`.